# App with many images

Tags: ios, image, memory-management

I have an app with lots of pictures (hundreds), for now I'm putting all of them in the Bundle, but now the app already occupies almost 50MB. Are there any other methods for not to consuming too much memory for applications with lots of images? How do I do that?

Comment: Well this totally depends on what kind of images they are, if they are fro the interface them you could definitely do something about it. But if they are photo's which need to be in app then you are out of luck, you might get some better compression if you use jpg instead of png.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the additional images from a server and store them on disk when the app runs the first time. Better still (depending on your app), only download and cache them on demand.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of these 2 ways:

1. If your image don't need transparency, use jpeg instead of png, lossy compression cost less disk space
2. Have your images hosted on your own server. The app download them on demand or at first app launch.

Comment: Be aware that loading a jpg is slower then loading a png, you could use 8 bit png's if they do not have that many colors.

Comment: @rckoenes do you have any reference to confirm this? (btw, I am quite sure _saving_ jpg is faster than png on iPhone, but no idea on reading speed)

Comment: Cocoanetics wrote a nice article on loading images: http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/10/avoiding-image-decompression-sickness/ But more importantly what kind of images are you using, for example using some image for button which you make stretchable instead of different images for all button sizes will make the app size way smaller. Use code to create gradients instead of images will increase the app size even more.(als it could speed things up) So without knowing the kind of images used you really can't say what step could decrease the app size.

Comment: nice one, great reading. BUT, in the article it state that loading a 1024x768 90% compression JPEG takes 527ms on iPhone 3G, and a crushed PNG with the same size takes 866ms on iPhone 3G. Shouldn't that means loading jpg is faster than loading png?

Comment: Yes for large images, but for small ones (mostly used for interface element) png is faster. So as my edit states you can't really anser the question since you don't no what kind of images ConicaDegenere is talking about.

Comment: I bet I can make a safe assumption that "pictures" are not small ones?